# Node has cached everything - Including routes and pages

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, session, caching

I have a Node/Express backend that serves as a proxying server for my Vue JS UI. I realised that once I log in with my Oauth on the server side, the session is available even after I restart the server. I tried restarting my app, and even my laptop. Moreover, I deleted some routes, and Node seems to have saved those too, I can access them even after deleting them.

Is there a way to fix this? I am using clientSessions to store the session.

Comment: If this is the [sessions module](https://www.npmjs.com/package/client-sessions) you're using, it looks like it uses client cookies to store session state.  You would have to delete or invalidate the cookies.  A server side store would give the server a bit more control, but you could probably also invalidate the cookies by changing your server secret.

Comment: Node does not save deleted route definitions.  Perhaps the browser is caching certain files itself?  Or you haven't actually restarted your server like you thought or I've even seen cases where people thought that they were editing their server source code and then restarting, but they were editing a copy of the code that wasn't what was being run.

Comment: Changing the secret seems to be a good suggestion, let me try that. I have a logout route that deletes the cookies, including the session cookie.